# How to keep the the number of patches fixed in Swin Transformer over the transformer blocks?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

I am using [video swin transformer](https://github.com/haofanwang/video-swin-transformer-pytorch/blob/main/video_swin_transformer.py) and a beginner in transformers. The input data has the shape:`x.shape: torch.Size([1, 1, 200, 8, 8])` and after going though the embedding and the layers, it gets the following changes in the shape (`Tiny Swin Transformer blocks`)

```
x = self.patch_embed(x)  # torch.Size([1, 96, 20, 8, 8])

x = self.pos_drop(x)
for layer in self.layers:
     x = layer(x.contiguous())

#Changes in the shape of x over the layers
layer 1, torch.Size([1, 192, 20, 4, 4])
layer 2, torch.Size([1, 384, 20, 2, 2])
layer 3, torch.Size([1, 768, 20, 1, 1])
layer 2, torch.Size([1, 768, 20, 1, 1])
```

I want to keep the dimension of the patch the same as it is processed by the swin transformer layers, while it is doing downsampling and the number of features are increasing over the layers. Is this possible?

```
layer 1, torch.Size([1, 192, 20, 8, 8])
layer 2, torch.Size([1, 384, 20, 8, 8])
layer 3, torch.Size([1, 768, 20, 8, 8])
layer 2, torch.Size([1, 768, 20, 8, 8])
```

If yes, how to change the code?
My window size is **(20,7,7)** and patch_size is **(10,1,1)**